# Display Hex and EBCDIC in a given 4 byte format - JAVA

Tags: java, hex

I am trying to display a HEX string in the below format:

```
48656C6C 6F20576F 48656C6C 48656C6C <THIS IS THE>
48656C6C 6F20576F 48656C6C 48656C6C <EBCDIC VALUE>
48656C6C 6F20576F 48656C6C 48656C6C <OF THE SIDE>
48656C6C 6F20576F 48656C6C 48656C6C <HEX CONVERSION>
48656C6C 6F20576F 48656C6C 48656C6C <BLAHH BLAHH>
48656C6C 6F20576F 48656C6C 48656C6C <B;AHH B;AHH>
48656C6C 6F20576F 48656C6C 48656C6C <B;AHH B;AHH>
```

The code I am using is below:

```
public void display(String hexValue)
{
    StringBuilder converted = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder raw = new StringBuilder();

    for( int i=0; i<hexValue.length()-1; i+=2 ){
        String output = hexValue.substring(i, (i + 2));
        raw.append(output);
        String value = this.ebcdicOfHex(output);
        converted.append(value);
        if (i%8 == 0 && i > 0) 
        {
            raw.append(" ");
        }
        if (i%32 == 0 && i > 0)
        {
          System.out.println(raw.toString() + " " + converted.toString());
          raw.setLength(0);
          converted.setLength(0);
        }       
    }

}
```

This method call is what makes my HEX to EBCDIC conversion from a lookup table

```
String value = this.ebcdicOfHex(output);
```

Its just that my code is displaying weird output for i=0 in the for loop. It``s taking the value till actual 34. I am not able to figure out how to handle that condition.

Comment: Solved it using i =2 as the start value and String output = hexValue.substring(i -2 , i) as the substring expression. I can paste in the code for the HEX to EBCDIC logic if anyone needs it!